# How to calculate foreign keys field in Django Admin then show in list

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I want to use Django to make a company management system.

So I chose Django Admin as the foundation.

I want the results of the calculation to be displayed in the Django Admin list.

Here is my code and error message:

models.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
    ID   = models.CharField(max_length=5, unique=True)
    NAME = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    STOCK= models.IntegerField(default=0)

class Order(models.Model):
    ID            = models.CharField(max_length=5, unique=True)
    Product       = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    day_sale_30   = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

admin.py

```
@admin.register(Product)
class Product(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass

@admin.register(Order)
class list_Order(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display=("NO", "Product", "day_sale_30", "daily_sales", "stock_divided_by_daily_sales")
    def daily_sales(self, obj):
        return obj.day_sale_30/30
    def stock_divided_by_daily_sales(self, obj):
        return obj.Product__STOCK/(obj.day_sale_30/30)
```

I got error as follows::

```
AttributeError at /admin/myapp/order/
'Order' object has no attribute 'Product__STOCK'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/myapp/order/
Django Version: 3.0.1
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'Order' object has no attribute 'Product__STOCK'
```

Thanks for helping!!!

Comment: What is `Product__STOCK`? Did you confuse it with `QTY`?

Comment: Sorry, typo, has been fixed. Thanks~!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using `obj.Product.STOCK` instead of `obj.Product__STOCK` will solve the issue